# AngularJS <select> view value not updated

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of models. I start with one model, then copy that model and push it to the stack. My view shows the array of models in one page.

But the view for the copied models isn't correct. More specifically the `<select>` isn't displaying the correct value.

Controller:

```
$scope.colors = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Green'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Red'
  }
];

var itemModel = {
  name: '',
  color: null
};

$scope.items = [
  angular.copy(itemModel)
];

$scope.copyItem = function(item) {
  $scope.items.push(angular.copy(item));
};
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/sVBL9j3JmCjdLZtr7HCH?p=preview

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<select ng-model="item.color" ng-options="color.name as color.name for color in colors">
    <option value="">None</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: It work's for the view part, but I lose the reference to color-object which I really don't want to.

Comment: Ok, give me a sec.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select ng-model="item.color" ng-options="color as color.name for color in colors track by color.id">
  <option value="">None</option>
</select>
```